# Why cast null before checking if object is equal to null?

Tags: c#, casting, null

I was looking through the "[Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0 Sample App](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/)" project and ran across some code that I do not understand.  In this project they often use syntax like the following to check arguments for null:

```
public GenericRepository(IQueryableContext context,ITraceManager traceManager)
{
    if (context == (IQueryableContext)null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context", Resources.Messages.exception_ContainerCannotBeNull);
```

Why would you cast null to the type of the object you are checking for null?

Comment: I don't think there is a reason at all, since `null` is `null` - it has no type.  They might be conforming to some *you should only check objects of the same type for equality* argument, but it seems a little ridiculous to me...

Comment: I dunno, maybe they think it's for readability/self documentation?

Comment: Where is this class in the domain model?

Comment: Off topic: Google already found this page, which I find to be amazing.  Just google "IQueryableContext" ...

Comment: @ItzWarty, SO probably pings them when new posts are added. I use a WordPress plugin that does this too.

Comment: @R0MANARMY The class is in the namespace "Microsoft.Samples.NLayerApp.Infrastructure.Data.Core".  The question wasn't specific to the type though, since this project does this check with many different types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pointless in the example given.

While not applicable in this case, there is sometimes a need to cast null (or at least there was before default(T) was added. Consider the following:

```
void DoSomething(string x) {
    ...
}

void DoSomething(object x) {
    ...
}

DoSomething(null);            // compiler can't infer the type
DoSomething((string)null);    // string type is now explicit
DoSomething(default(string)); // same as previous
```

**EDIT**

Just thought of another case where you would have to do the cast when testing equality. If you had an object that had an overloaded == operator that allowed comparison with two reference types, comparing against null would be ambiguous. However because IQueryableContext is most likely an interface and interfaces cannot overload the == operator, I still don't see any valid reason to do it in the example you gave.

```
class CustomObject {

    private string _id;

    public CustomObject(string id) {
        _id=id;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(CustomObject lhs, CustomObject rhs) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs)) { return true; }
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)) { return false; }
        if (ReferenceEquals(rhs, null)) { return false; }
        return lhs._id == rhs._id;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(CustomObject lhs, CustomObject rhs) {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(CustomObject lhs, string rhs) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs)) { return true; }
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)) { return false; }
        if (ReferenceEquals(rhs, null)) { return false; }
        return lhs._id == rhs;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(CustomObject lhs, string rhs) {
        return !(lhs==rhs);
    }

}

CustomObject o = null;
if (o == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("I don't compile.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer.  In the project I mentioned they do use this same type of null check on concrete types as well.

Comment: But I should add that anyone that did this with a class should be hunted down and killed by the smoke monster. It would put a ton of undue stress and confusion on anyone that used the type.

Comment: Just another case: explicit null casting is also necessary when using the "?:" conditional operator (or ternary operator, as I knew it in the old days). Example:
DateTime? someVar = 0 > 1 ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime?)null;

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't do a cast. There's no reason for it in this case.

Comment: That's what I thought.  It's just so odd since its a Microsoft sponsored open source project to provide best practices, and there seems to be no point to it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to cast null in the given example.  It might be for legibility... I don't know, I wouldn't do this =P

In some cases [which doesn't include the case covered in this topic] you have to cast to INullable before you can check to see if a variable is null.  Otherwise, you have to use object==default(TypeOfObject)...